# Как изменить стартовую страницу у Opera?

Tags: opera

Есть файл где хранятся настройки opera:

> C:\Users\имя пользователя\AppData\Roaming\Opera Software\Opera Stable\Preferences

В нём есть параметр `startup_urls:[]`. Мой парсер (написанный на Delphi) ищет его и изменяет добавляя `Site.ru` потом файл сохраняет.

Дело в том что опера при запуске возрождает старые настройки! Как это обойти?

Comment: Как это связано с программированием?

Comment: Мне бы через Delphi это всё сделать

Comment: Уверены, что парсер работает? Строка точно заменяется? Измененный файл корректно сохраняется? Чего конкретно Вы хотите добиться? Вопрос весьма непонятный. Перефразируйте его. Сейчас вообще не ясно, как Делфи может помочь с предотвращением загрузки Оперой старых настроек.

Comment: Он изменяет параметр startup_urls и ещё параметр который делает так чтобы открывалась стартовая страница, стартовая страница ставится и другой параметр тоже страница добавляется но не изменяется пункт в настройках чтобы загружалась стартовая страница а не новая вкладка или последняя страница

Comment: На Вашем месте, чтобы не тратить время впустую, я бы полистал/написал на форум Оперы. Может там есть объяснение такому поведению.

Comment: Я уже понял что это защита которая не даёт посторонним программам изменять!

Comment: Откуда такая информация? Если она корректна - оформите ответ, чтобы другие люди, которые столкнутся с подобным, могли понять, в каком направлении им двигаться дальше.